# Storing a textarea's value into a database table

Tags: database, tinymce

How can you get the value of a `<textarea>` and store it in a MySQL database table?

I'm using TinyMCE 3.3.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as no one has answered your question I thought I'd chip in. Have you ever managed to get any form data passed into a database before (I.E is it just accessing a textarea that's the problem), or is this a general question about how to put form data into databases?

One thing I would strongly recommend is moving away from WYSIWYG style editors if your seriously considering doing web development properly. From experience no matter how good they claim to be you'll always encounter cross browser problems and at some point you'll have to dig into the code and understand it.

Sorry this isn't a direct answer, but with a bit more info as to what you need to know I'm sure we can help... I warn you though, if you've not had much experience at this some of the answers could be a bit deep. I think maybe this is why you've not had any responses because the answer require could potentially be quite epic,lol.

Dan

Comment: WYSIWYG editors are pretty neat and it is not that difficult to store the contetns in a db. i guess it depends on the use case to decide if the usage of a WYSIWYG editor is beneficial

Answer (score 0):

The tinymce editor id equals the textarea id.
Assuming that `editor` is your tinymce editor instance you may use the following to get the textareaa content (which is then equal to the editor content).

```
editor.triggerSave(); // update the textarea
var textarea_element = document.getElementById(editor.id); // get the updated textarea
var content = textarea_element.innerHTML;  // this is the content

// now you need to call a script to save the content (i suggest you use ajax)
...
```